# Python - Prompt in a variable

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to figure out how to do an exercise on this book: "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 3 Documentation Release 3rd Edition".

This is the code that I've to modify:

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("lightgreen") # Set the window background color
window.title("Hello, Tess!") # Set the window title
tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color("blue") # Tell tess to change her color
tess.pensize(3) # Tell tess to set her pen width
tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)
window.mainloop()
```

This is the request: Modify this program so that before it creates the window, it prompts the user to enter the desired background color. It should store the user’s 
responses in a variable, and modify the color of the window according to the user’s wishes. Do similar changes to allow the user, at runtime, to set tess’ color.

This is how I did it:

```
import turtle
window = turtle.Screen()
windowcolor = input ("window color: ")
tesscolor = input ("tess color: ")
window.bgcolor = windowcolor # Set the window background color
window.title("Hello, Tess!") # Set the window title
tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color = tesscolor # Tell tess to change her color
tess.pensize(3) # Tell tess to set her pen width
tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)
window.mainloop()
```

The ploblem is that the screen and the arrow didn't change colors at all...
Help me please. Thanks

Edoardo

[Turtle like AKG said](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tquh.png)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Note the difference between the first code, `window.bgcolor("lightgreen")` and your modified code, `window.bgcolor = windowcolor`. Ditto of course for `tess`.

Comment: You are right but if I try with with window.gbcolor("variableofcolor") I've the error I put at the end of my post...

Comment: Remove the quotes: `window.bgcolor(windowcolor)`. `"lightgreen"` is a `str` value in itself, while `windowcolor` is a *variable* that holds a `str` value.

Comment: Sorry, I mean window.gbcolor(variableofcolor) and I have TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

Comment: If you use `gbcolor` instead of `gbcolor`, you need to fix your typo. If you have a `str` error, you have liked assigned that instance variable to something else before using the suggested line.

Comment: Sorry I can't undestand what you said... can you write me out the solution please?

Comment: It appears you're running into various beginners problems and misconceptions. Your current questions diverge from the actual question asked; I would suggest you ask instead on a Python beginners mailing list or forum, such as [Python tutor](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) or [LearnPython](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/), since your question becomes too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You were calling `window.bgcolor()` and `tess.color()` in your original code with the hard-coded values, so you need to also *call* `window.bgcolor()` and `tess.color()` with the new values. Now you're just overwriting the functions with those values.

So something like this...

```
import turtle

windowcolor = input("window color: ")
tesscolor = input("tess color: ")

# Set up window

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor(windowcolor)
window.title("Hello, Tess!")

# Set up turtle

tess = turtle.Turtle()
tess.color(tesscolor)
tess.pensize(3)

# Draw things

tess.forward(50)
tess.left(120)
tess.forward(50)

# Enter window loop

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I already tried to do as you said, but I've this error: 
  File "/home/edx/.config/spyder/turtlescreencolor.py", line 17, in <module>
    window.bgcolor(windowcolor)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @EdoardoZucchelli, this code worked for me.  Perhaps you're running it under Python 3 and inputing "blue" with quotes (ala Python 2) instead of just typing: blue